# Not able to browse the central admin after installing sharepoint 2010 on windows 7

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i sucussfully installed sharepoint 2010. configuration also went succesfully. after that when i open central administration it is giving 500 error like The website cannot display the page.
please anyone can help me in this

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

See if any relevant Windows services on your Windows 7 box have been disabled or not restarted  properly.
The Central Admin site may be failing as SQL is not accessible.

Also verify the Central Admin site is ok in IIS Manager:  check that the application pool or site itself has not stopped.

Answer (score 0):

By default, some of the authentication providers may not be installed in Windows 7 machine (inside IIS). You can check the list of authentication providers by double click on the central administration site in IIS